# MySQL : Access is Denied

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem when I try to connect with an external MySQL server

Here the error message :

> acces is denied for user :  `"user"@"myip"`

When I change port number, I get different error :

```
$connection =mysql_connect("192.96.206.145:8443","user","password")or die( mysql_error() );
if(!$connection)
{
    echo 'It\'s impossible to connect with the server ! check you connection or try later ';
    //exit;    
}
else
{    
    if (!mysql_select_db($gamedatabase,$connection))
    {
        echo'we have problem in our server plz try again later ! ';
        //exit;    
    }
    else
    {
        $etat=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I strongly recommend you not to use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and no longer be used in future versions of PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 different Server :
**Server A** : Apache + PHP 
**Server B** : MySQL

Go to the **Server A** 
Get his IP address : you can type `ipconfig` command
(*I will suppose that the IP address is **SO_IP***)

Go to the **Server B**
Add `MySql\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable
Executes these commands :

```
mysql --user=root mysql
CREATE USER 'SO_USER'@'SO_IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'SO_PASS';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'SO_USER'@'SO_IP' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Return to your **Server A** and change the **PHP** connection code

```
$connection =mysql_connect("SERVER_B_IP_ADDRESS:3306","SO_USER","SO_PASS")or die( mysql_error() );
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that your MySQL-Server is running on Port 8443? Normally, that is 3306.

Is your MySQL server and user enabled for external access? I mean bind_address and the settings in the user table of MySQL. (Is there any firewall blocking access?)

Furthermore, you should MySQLi-extension as MySQL is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

This error is characteristic of an incorrect database password. If it's giving you an access denied error that means that it can find the database, it just can't log in to it with the provided information.

Also may I suggest using mysqli instead of mysql, as the improved version is much more secure.

Double check your password. Can you access the database by any other means such as phpmyadmin / a database editor such as navicat?